# Движение imageView

Tags: android

Как заставить двигаться по экрану imageView в андроид по математическому закону(скажем sin или cos) ?

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень расплывчатый. Если не говорить о математических законах, то почему бы не попробовать transition animation?

Comment: уточню: некий метод вычисляет декартовы координаты и передвигает imageView

Comment: интересует код этого метода